# Image field error showing message

Tags: theming

When I create a new content type with an image field, the image alternative text shows this error message.

> This value should be of the correct primitive type.

The image isn't shown in the view.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/2220381) for a core/contributed module, which we can't help with here